# How to uninstall PhoneGap from my project and machine

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I need to uninstall the PhoneGap library completely from my system and from Xcode. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To uninstall:

1. Remove the PHONEGAPLIB value in Xcode Preferences -> Source Trees
2. Delete the ~/Documents/PhoneGapLib folder
3. Delete the ~/Library/Application
   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project  Templates/PhoneGap folder
4. Delete the "~/Library/Application
   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Templates/Project
   Templates/Application/PhoneGap-based Application.xctemplate" or the "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project\ Templates/Application/PhoneGap-based\ Application.xctemplate" folder
5. Delete the /Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework
   folder
6. Delete the ~/Library/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework symlink

Answer (score 33):

if you've installed PhoneGap via `npm`, you can easily uninstall it via:

> sudo npm uninstall -g phonegap

Answer (score 5):

I used the official uninstall script:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/callback/phonegap-iphone/trunk/Uninstall%20PhoneGap.applescript

Comment: This worked for me along with `sudo npm uninstall -g phonegap`