# How to uninstall Phonegap from Mac OS X 10.7.3?

Tags: iphone, ios5, cordova

I am very new to iPhone development. I am looking to work with the PhoneGap Framework. I want to uninstall the Phonegap framework version 2.0.0 from my XCode and also from my Mac. I have searched Google to solve this problem, but I can't find any idea from there. And also I am very new to development.

Could you please help me solve this issue and run the project? Thanks in advance. Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Uninstall PhoneGap from my Project and Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427696/how-to-uninstall-phonegap-from-my-project-and-machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the **Cordova-1.7.3.dmg** from the path **PhoneGap/phonegap-phonegap-de1960d/lib/ios**

   Click and open it. You can see the window same as below , then click on **Uninstall Cordova** option.

[image]

2. Use the phonegap [uninstall script](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/callback/phonegap-iphone/trunk/Uninstall%20PhoneGap.applescript)

Comment: I can't find that folder, but this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10599061/2647345

Comment: @LucTheRedstoner: thank you very much for pointing out. I have updated the answer. Please kindly note that, I have wrote the old answer based on the old Mac OS X versions (year of 2012).